# TSQL Sum a value based on a double ID value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is a small simplified snipped of my data

```
OrderID  QTY  ItemID  ActualQTY(does not exist in database)
1        2    1       
2        1    2
3        1    1
4        5    3
```

Now I need a query that will fill in the `ActualQTY` based on the `ItemID's`. So summing total QTY for `ItemID 1 = 3`, and for `ItemID 2 = 1`, and last for `ItemID 3 = 5`

It should look like this

```
OrderID  QTY  ItemID  ActualQTY
1        2    1       3
2        1    2       1
3        1    1       3
4        5    3       5
```

The problem is I am new to TSQL and I can't figure out a good way to do this.

--EDIT--

Someone else helped me with this problem and gave this solution which seems like the most efficient solution to me. However this solution doesn't work if you need to apply them to an XSD file in visual studio. So I turned it into a table valued function on the server.

```
SELECT OrderID, QTY, ItemID, SUM(QTY) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID) AS ActualQTY
```

So if this solution doesn't work resort to answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  t2.OrderID,
  t2.QTY,
  t2.ItemID,
  t1.ActualQTY
FROM
(
   SELECT 
     ItemId,
     SUM(QTY) AS ActualQTY
   FROM tablename AS t1
   GROUP BY ItemId
) AS t1
INNER JOIN tablename AS t2 ON t1.ItemId = t2.ItemID;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63c80/1)

---

But if you want to update the column `ActualQTY` values, not just select, you can do this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.ActualQTY = t2.ActualQTY
FROM tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 
     ItemId,
     SUM(QTY) AS ActualQTY
   FROM tablename AS t1
   GROUP BY ItemId
) AS t2 ON t1.ItemID = t2.ItemID
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08e7d/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.OrderID,
       b.QTY,
       b.ItemID,
       a.total_sum AS ActualQTY
FROM   (SELECT ItemID,
               Sum(QTY) AS total_sum
        FROM   tablename
        GROUP  BY ItemID) AS a
       INNER JOIN tablename b
               ON a.ItemID = b.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t.orderid, t.qty, t.itemid, a.actualq as actualqty
From yourtable t join (
   Select sum(qty) as actualq, itemid
   From yourtable
   Group by itemid) a
On t.itemid = a.itemid
```